# NgRx: load list of items, and after for each load item them status

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to display a list of items to the user in 2 steps.
First the simple list in a single request to an API.
Then when it's done, load the status of each item one by one with multiple requests to an API.
the first list is quick to obtain, on the other hand the call to the status is much longer for each item.
I use Angular 13 + NgRx.
I would like to know the right approach.
Here is where I am but it does not work.

effect :

```
getDatafacts$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_START),
switchMap((action) => {
  return this.apiService.callApi("GET", "neotimo/datafact/getdatafactqueue", null)
    .pipe(
      map(result => {

        const queue = <DataFactQueueResult>result;
        queue.dataFactItems.forEach((item) => {
          this.apiService.callApi("GET", "neotimo/datafact/getdatafactitem", item.id.toString())
            .subscribe(
              value => DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_UPDATESTATUS({ payload: <DataFactItemResult>value })
            )
        });
        
        return DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_SUCCESS({ payload: queue });
      }),
      catchError(errorRes => {
        switch (errorRes.status) {
          case 403:
          case 401:
            return of(DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_FAIL({ payload: [this.errorAccessDenied] }));
          case 404:
            return of(DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_FAIL({ payload: [this.error404] }));
          case 400:
            return of(DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_FAIL({ payload: [errorRes.error.errors[0].message] }));
          default:
            return of(DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_FAIL({ payload: [this.errorOccured] }));
        }
      })
    )
}))
```

Reducer :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create and return an array with all the actions that you want to dispatch like in [this example](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22). This array should include all `DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_UPDATESTATUS({ payload: <DataFactItemResult>value }` from foreach and also `DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_SUCCESS({ payload: queue });`

Right now I think you dispatch only this action:

`DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_SUCCESS({ payload: queue });`

**Edit:**

I would also create another action and effect for this api call:

```
 this.apiService.callApi("GET", "neotimo/datafact/getdatafactitem", item.id.toString())
            .subscribe(
              value => DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_UPDATESTATUS({ payload: <DataFactItemResult>value })
        )
```

The new effect will return `DataFactActions.GET_QUEUE_UPDATESTATUS`.

Then, inside the foreach from getDatafacts$ instead of calling directly the api, I would construct an array with the new action and then return this array.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the ngrx-loading-state lib:

https://github.com/amzhang/ngrx-loading-state

spoiler alert, I'm the author :)

Live demo that tracks the loading state of individual items:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rocjzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

(go to the "Id Loading State Demo" tab)

It's boilerplatey, but then again, working with NgRx is never terse.

The loading states exist as entities in the store, so you can reactively display their state in the UI without polluting the entities in the store that holds the API results.

**Loading states can be parameterised by an item ID, which is what you want here.**